# How to run polybar ubuntu 22.04 with apt

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, snap

I've been trying to install polybar on my Ubuntu laptop using:

`sudo apt install polybar`

or

`sudo snap install polybar-git --edge`

but with both I can't seem to get the example running and get the error:
`error: Define configuration using --config=PATH`.

By default I did not have the folder ~/.config/polybar so I created it and added a config.ini file but was never able to specify the path like the error said. Does someone know what's going on ?

Comment: Please clarity did you install it or not? Title says you can not install it and body of the question says it is installed and you can not run it.

Comment: You might want to read through https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki

Comment: Yes my probleme has to do with runing rather than install

Answer (score 0):

The package `polybar` does not automatically install a configuration file. You need to create one yourself.

At least one bar must be configured in the configuration file. In contrast to previous versions, you need to specify the name of the defined bar, even if there is a single one, when launching polybar. The man page, `man polybar`, points to resources on the internet for how to set it up.

Comment: That was my asumption so I did try to create a the folder with a config file in it. I think my problem is that I don't know how to properly indicate the path with the command ```polybar --config=PATH``` every time I try to use it just displays the help information and I still get the same error, am I not doing that correctly ?

Comment: You do not need the --config option if your config file is in either of the locations I indicated.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense so I copied the example file from the location you specified and I added it to ```/etc/polybar/``` and I tried to run ```polybar example``` but still the same error, is there some more steps to take ?

Comment: The polybar version in ubuntu 22.04 (polybar 3.5.7) does not load from `/etc/polybar` by default, it only looks at `~/.config/polybar/config`.

Comment: Indeed, you will need to consult the documention for the current  version. The crucial point of my answer is that no default config is installed, so that should help you forward.